# Reading items from list and display it as string

Tags: c#, list, datagridview

I have an list with an object datatype which i'm trying to fill and then read out to a string. The list should hold data for each column in a DataGridView:

```
[Serializable]
public sealed class ColumnOrderItem
{
    public int DisplayIndex { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
    public int ColumnIndex { get; set; }
}

private void test()
{

List<ColumnOrderItem> columnOrder = new List<ColumnOrderItem>();
                DataGridViewColumnCollection columns = dsgDataGrid.Columns;
                for (int i = 0; i < columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    columnOrder.Add(new ColumnOrderItem
                    {
                        ColumnIndex = i,
                        DisplayIndex = columns[i].DisplayIndex,
                        Visible = columns[i].Visible,
                        Width = columns[i].Width

                    });
                }

                colData = string.Join(",", columnOrder);

MessageBox.Show(colData);
}
```

what I'm expecting is the MessageBox should display each item value in sequence like DisplayIndex, Width, Visible, ColumnIndex, DisplayIndex, Width, Visible, ColumnIndex...and so on. The problem is that all i get read back is 0,1,2 which seems to be just the ColumnIndex for the 3 columns under the dsgDataGrid which is a DataGridView. Does anyone have any idea how i might output all the data to a single string?

Thanks.

Comment: Try overriding the ToString method in ColumnOrderItem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best option for you is [override the ToString method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173154.aspx) Hence your class definition will be like the following:

```
[Serializable]
public sealed class ColumnOrderItem
{
    public int DisplayIndex { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
    public int ColumnIndex { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder overRideString = new StringBuilder();
        overRideString.AppendLine("DisplayIndex" + DisplayIndex.ToString());
        overRideString.AppendLine("Width" + Width.ToString());
        overRideString.AppendLine("Visible" + Visible.ToString());
        overRideString.AppendLine("ColumnIndex" + ColumnIndex.ToString());
        return overRideString.ToString();
    }
}
```

**How to use:**

```
StringBuilder details = new StringBuilder();   
foreach (ColumnOrderItem item in columnOrder)
{
   details.AppendLine(item.ToString());  
}
details.ToString(); // this will give you the required result
```

Comment: `string.Join<T> Method (String, IEnumerable<T>)` should do practically the same as your `How to use` example.

Comment: The only thing that I suppose wrong is the fact the the OP wants output for a single item in a single line. But I suppose...

Answer (score 2):

You can define `ToString` for `ColumnOrderItem` and use

THX  for informing me about the implict calling of `ToString` by `String.join`   @Neijwiert

Eg:

```
public string ToString()
{
  return string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}",
               this.ColumnIndex,
               this.DisplayIndex,
               this.Visible,
               this.Width);
}
```

When you call `String.join(spliter,enums:IEnumerable<T>)`

It works the same as `String.join(spliter,enums.Select(i->i.toString()))`

> Join(String, IEnumerable) is a convenience method that lets you concatenate each member of an IEnumerable collection without first converting them to strings. The string representation of each object in the IEnumerable collection is derived by calling that object's ToString method.

[String.Join Method (String, IEnumerable)-MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: No need to use lambda expression to invoke ToString. `string.Join<T> Method (String, IEnumerable<T>)` already does that.

Comment: Err,I'm not sure if join would do that as I have not tested it. Thx for telling me.

Answer (score 0):

you might have to add a ToString override in your ColumnOrderItem Class like :

```
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format(
                "[DisplayIndex: {0}, Width: {1}, Visible: {2}, ColumnIndex: {3}]\n",
                DisplayIndex,
                Wi`enter code here`dth,
                Visible,
                ColumnIndex);


        }
```

then when you do `var colData = string.Join(",", columnOrder);` this should give you the output you wanted for example[image]

Comment: Although already answered, it does contain an example which uses `string.Join`. However, you should use `StringBuilder` for these kind of things.